# Odoo v15, better way to write this .xml?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

Is it a better way to write this code? I think is not very clean to write the same attr 3 times, it could be better if I can have 3 `expr` in the same `xpath` tag

```
<record id="sale_margin_sale_order_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.margin.sale.order.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_margin.sale_margin_sale_order"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='margin']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//span[hasclass('oe_inline')]" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//label[@for='margin']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Try to hide the parent `div` instead of the field and span

Comment: That should be the answer